# How to parse SQL dump file in PHP?

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, regex, preg-match-all

I have a hugh SQL Server dump file with a lot of tables, views, etc.

I want to be able to get all content between 2 lines starting with create and finishing with go.

I'm able to retrieve type and name with this expresion

```php
'~^(create)\\s(assembly|aggregate|table|synonym|trigger|view|function|procedure)\\s([^\\s\#\(]+)([\\s|\(])~im'
```

But I dont know how to get the content between CREATE and GO, data from file looks like, name or content inside could have 'go' as string but never as start line

```sql
CREATE view [dbo].[name]
***************************
GO
PRINT N'Creando [dbo].[other]...';


GO

CREATE VIEW  [dbo].[other] as      
**************************
GO
```

Regards